# Logstash: create url-friendly _id for documents

Tags: url, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using the `fingerprint` plugin to create custom `_id` fields that **should** be base64 encoded:

```
  fingerprint {
    key => "somekey"
    base64encode => true
    method => "SHA512"
    source => [ "username" ]
    target =>  "[@metadata][custom_id]"
   }

   truncate {
    fields =>  "[@metadata][custom_id]"
    length_bytes => 20
   }
```

However, here is an example key that was created:

`lStqstfpWw5OHe+B3FBi`

The above is **NOT** url friendly therefore manipulation by id becomes cumbersome since it needs encoding/decoding.

Any suggestion to make the `_id` url friendly?

Comment: One of the possible char used in base64 encoding is the + (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table)). I think you should remove the `base64encode => true`, you'd get an hex encoding, which would be url friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing this at some point, in conformance with [RFC3548](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3548.html) and its guidelines on base64-urlfriendliness ...

```
mutate {
  gsub => [
    "[@metadata][custom_id]", "\+", "-",
    "[@metadata][custom_id]", "/", "_"
    ]
}
```